# Chef point to local recipe dependency

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

I have 2 cookbooks, A and and B, where A includes recipe B. Normally, recipes are pulled from the chef server, however, I want to make a change to cookbook B, and ensure that change does not break recipe A before pushing the changes to cookbook B to the Chef Server.

How to I specify in my metadata.rb file of cookbook A that I want to use my local cookbook B, as opposed to one that is on the server?

Comment: Have you considered using test kitchen or vagrant to test cookbooks? Berkshelf is a tool for managing cookbook versions.

Comment: Yes, we use vagrant as well.

Answer (score 1):

I appeared to have been looking in the wrong place, the metadata.rb was not the place where I should have been making this change, it should have been in the Berksfile.

The the following line added to the end of the Berksfile solvede the problem:

```
cookbook "B", path: '/path/to/cookbook/B'
```